powershell how to display only the names of directories (except one) and subdirectories?
I want to display the directories and subdirectories in PowerShell (therefore in recursive mode) by excluding a directory located at the root. I tried with the following script: The exclusion works well because (note: I tried with "Exclude," but it did not work.) But my main problem is that it displays all files! In fact, I would only like to display the names of directories and subdirectories. Thanks a lot.
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\" -include "*.*" -Recurse |  
  ?{$_.fullname -notlike "C:\Pictures\*"} | 
  %{ADD-content -path "C:\result.txt" -value $_.FullName}

 


Get-ChildItem has the parameter -Directory. This will only show directories

To see the options for Get-childItem you can call Get-Help -full Get-ChildItem or just call help -full GCI. There you will find the option -Attributes which os what you need:
Get-ChildItem -Attributes Directory -Path "C:\" -include "*.*" -Recurse |  
  ?{$_.fullname -notlike "C:\Pictures\*"} | 
  %{ADD-content -path "C:\result.txt" -value $_.FullName}


-Directory would be better than -Attributes Directory

@phuclv Better? In which way? More performant? That should be benchmarked. Less to type? Of course! More posibilites to "filter"? No way, -Attributes ... is better in that case. So: It depends.

Better in the sense that -Directory directly, succinctly and exclusively expresses the intent to limit the output to directories only; it is the PowerShell-idiomatic way to express this intent.
Using a different, multi-purpose parameter to indirectly achieve the same thing is obscure, verbose, and overkill in this case.


Use the -Directory switch of Get-ChildItem to limit output to directories (similarly, if you wanted files only, you'd use -File).

-Include *.* only matches names that contain at least one . character, which is not what you want. -Include uses PowerShell's wildcard expressions, which don't exhibit the legacy quirks of the wildcards supported by the file-system APIs; to use the latter, use the -Filter parameter instead.

-Filter is generally preferable, beceuse it is much faster due to filtering at the source (instead of enumerating all items first and then letting PowerShell apply filtering), but - unlike -Include - it is limited to a single pattern and exhibits the legacy quirks, as noted.

While you therefore could use -Filter *.*, there's no good reason to, as you seemingly want to return all directories, irrespective of their name, so filtering isn't needed at all.



Indeed, -Exclude can not be used to exclude entire subdirectory trees (a limitation you're already trying to work around with ? {$_.fullname -notlike "C:\Pictures\*"}), because the specified pattern is matched against the items on each level of the directory hierarchy while not preventing recursing into excluded directories.

However, -notlike "C:\Pictures\*" isn't sufficient, because it doesn't exclude C:\Pictures itself, only its subdirectories.

-notmatch '^C:\\Pictures($|\\)' fixes that problem, using a regex with the -notmatch operator.

GitHub issue #15159 is a feature request to support subtree exclusion in the future.



For performance reasons, do not call file-writing commands repeatedly, once for each pipeline input object, which is what you're doing with Add-Content inside your % (ForEach-Object) call.

Instead, pipe directly to a file-writing cmdlet, which means that a single invocation receives all input to write. Since you're therefore then writing the target file as a whole, you can switch from Add-Content to Set-Content.



To put it all together (using simplified syntax and full cmdlet names rather than aliases):
Get-ChildItem C:\ -Directory -Recurse |  
  Where-Object FullName -notmatch '^C:\\Pictures($|\\)' | 
  ForEach-Object FullName |
  Set-Content C:\result.txt 


Thank you very much for your help!!  but unfortunately the script does not work: it still does not exclude the indicated directory for me...???

@Jean, my bad: I didn't spot that -notlike "C:\Pictures\*" doesn't exclude C:\Pictures itself, only its subdirectories. Please see my update, which fixes this problem by using -notmatch with a regex that covers both cases.

@Jean, the answer you accepted only matches directories whose names contain a . character, as discussed in this answer, which I presume is not your intent. If you fix that problem - by omitting the -Include argument altogether, as noted in this answer - ?{$_.fullname -notlike "C:\Pictures\*"} will not exclude C:\Pictures, itself, only its subdirectories, as discussed in my previous comment. When accepting answers, please consider future readers: an accepted answer that doesn't (fully) solve the problem described in the question is a confusing distraction.
